# Law of Cosines for very acute angles, round-off error

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods

We have
$$
c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\cos(\gamma)
$$

If $a \approx b$ and $\gamma$ is very small, then the above formulation has quite a bit of round-off error.

Is there a better formulation that would help to reduce some of the error?

Comment: I have not learnt numerical methods formally, but whenever I have to approximate $\cos A$ where $A$ is small, what I do is to convert it into $1-2\sin^2 (A/2)$ and that works for most of the times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the algebra from the other answer, it seems like a better approximation would be:
$$
c^2 =  (a - b)^2 + 4ab\sin^2(\gamma/2)
$$
You'll still get some subtractive cancellation when computing $a-b$, but it's not as bad as the original formula.

Also, when $\gamma$ is small, calculating $\sin\gamma$ accurately is easier than calculating $\cos\gamma$.

Comment: how is that different from my answer? If you've added some technical stuff from the theory of numerical methods, then fine (subtractive cancellation??), but it seems that it is just the same is mine.

Comment: @Parth -- it's different in a few small ways. First, I thought you were suggesting the approximation $c = a\gamma$, which isn't very good. Second, you focussed entirely on the cosine problem. The other problem is the subtractive cancellation that occurs in $a^2 + b^2 - 2ab$. My formula reduces that problem. Mathematically, all the formulae are the same, but in floating point arithmetic (which is the crux of the question) they are quite different.

Comment: well, I was indeed suggesting that approximation. Why isn't that a good approximation? What I thought was (maybe quite naively since I haven't learnt all this; just fiddling around with whatever little knowledge I have) - OP said $a$ and $b$ are nearly equal. So I took $a^2 \approx b^2 \implies a^2+b^2-2ab \approx 0$. Is this wrong/bad approximation?

Comment: @Parth -- it's not "wrong", but you threw away a lot of terms, and the approximation can be improved by keeping a few more of them (which is what I did).

Comment: Well okay then. Thanks for telling all that! :D

Answer (score 3):

What I told in my comment works!

$$ c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\cos(\gamma) $$

$$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab(1-2\sin^2(\gamma/2)) \\ = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab + 4ab\sin^2(\gamma/2) $$

Applying the approximations:

$$c^2 \approx a^2 + a^2 - 2a^2 + 4^2a^2(\gamma^2/4) = a^2\gamma^2$$

So, $$ c \approx a\gamma $$

Now, your condition is such that you have two long sides $a$ and $b$, nearly equal and the opposite side is $c$. This is similar to having a circle of radius $a = b$ and your $c$ being the arc subtended by the angle $\gamma$. Doesn't the result agree with the arc length formula?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is helpful:
Insert $2ab-2ab$:
$$c^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2 - 2ab(\cos(\gamma)-1) \\
c^2 = (a-b)^2  - 2ab(\cos(\gamma)-1) \\
$$
let $a=b+\delta$ and also expand the taylor-series of the $\cos()$ then
$$c^2 = \delta^2  - 2(b+\delta)b(-\gamma^2/2 + \gamma^4/4!...) \\
c^2 = \delta^2  + 2(b+\delta)b(\gamma^2/2 - \gamma^4/4!...) \\
c^2 =  2b^2(\gamma^2/2 - \gamma^4/4!...) +  \delta(2 b(\gamma^2/2 - \gamma^4/4!...) +\delta)\\
$$
[update] After some more fiddling with this an example might be more instructive. Letting $b=3$, $\delta=1e-6$ and $\gamma=1e-6$ the best approximation is already $c^2 \approx 2b^2 \gamma^2/2 + \delta^2 $ , if we look at the evaluation of the three summands separately, where we evaluate the $1-\cos(\gamma)$ only up to its first term :$$ 2b^2 (\gamma^2/2)=9.0 E-12 \\ 2b\delta (\gamma^2/2)=3.0 E-18 \\ \delta^2= 1.0 E-12$$ and we see, that only the first and the third summand are relevant.